# Connecting maven with liquibase with hibernate?

Tags: hibernate, maven, liquibase

I have a Maven-based project which uses Hibernate and Postgres (No Spring).

I want to use Liquibase for database migrations. Ideally, I'd like the following workflow:

1. I create the initial "changeset" (mvn liquibase:generateChangeLog ?)  which is supposed to initialize the database.
2. I add Entity classes with appropriate annotations. I generate a "diff"   changeset (mvn liquibase:diff ?) and check it into the repository.
3. now everybody in my team pulls from the repository and runs something (mvn update?) to get their copy of the database up to date.
4. I repeat previous two steps as desired.
   I understand that Liquibase is supposed to support this kind of dev workflow. The trouble is, there are many moving parts and I'm struggling with connecting things together

e.g., how do I configure the Liquibase, in Maven? in liquibase.properties? How do I specify where my changesets are to be stored?, How do I create the initial "changeset"? I understand changesets could be in different formats, (XML, JSON and so on) what are the pros and cons, can they be simply be in SQL?

Answer (score 0):

There is a maven plugin for liquibase for having this done through maven based solution.

http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/maven/generated/update-mojo.html

you can then run your maven build with goal  liquibase:update

for example if you want to connect to mysql DB ( liquibase supports many different databases )

```
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.6</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>





<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
            <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <promptOnNonLocalDatabase>false</promptOnNonLocalDatabase>
                <changeLogFile>${changelog}</changeLogFile>
                <driver>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver>
                <url>jdbc:mysql://${mysql.host}:${mysql.port}/${mysql.schema}</url>
                <username>${mysql.username}</username>
                <password>${mysql.password}</password>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

we can integrate with hibernate as well and there is a project in github please check their documentation of doing it through hibernate.

https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase-hibernate/releases

Hope this answers your question

edited:

```
liquibase --driver=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver \
      --classpath=\path\to\classes:jdbcdriver.jar \
      --changeLogFile=com/example/db.changelog.xml \
      --url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE" \
      --username=scott \
      --password=tiger \
      generateChangeLog
```

this will generate the changelog for existing database.

Refer - http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/generating_changelogs.html

refer - http://bytefilia.com/managing-database-schema-changes-liquibase-existing-schema/

*Note that this command currently has some limitations. It does not export the following types of objects:
Stored procedures, functions, packages
Triggers*

Comment: I am aware of this plug-in, thanks.
How, using this plugin to generate the initial changeset on a new project?
I know too that it integrates with Hibernate and "mvn liquibase:diff" can figure out changes in the model, at least in theory (it gave me NullPointerException on a simple project for some reason).